# MacOs list package install via curl

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, macports

Is there a way to find the list of packages that have been installed via curl?

For example I installed the following two packages:

Bun:

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

Maestro:

```
curl -Ls "https://get.maestro.mobile.dev" | bash
```

For example with npm I can do like this:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

For example with brew I can do this:

```
brew list
```

I wanted to know the list of other elements installed via curl.

Answer (score 7):

No.

You're not "installing via curl".  You're using `curl` to download an installer, which you then run.  In your two examples, you're downloading a shell script that you're then piping into `bash`.

Comment: So I have no way to know what I installed in the past?

Comment: In general no you don't. The partial exception is full Applications if you put them in /Applications. This is one reason to use a package manager like macports or homebre (or Mac App Store)

Comment: To clarify using curl is exaclylik like downloading via a web browser like Safari and then running what you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could `grep` your `history` for `curl` entries, but as others have mentioned, this won't give you any connection with what has been installed.  Also, `history` typically has a fairly short retention period.

You could also use `pkg-util` to view package (.pkg) receipts, but this won't have anything to do with `curl` and also won't show anything downloaded and installed by other means (for example, from a mounted .DMG).

Comment: At the moment I tried with: `history|grep "curl"`.